# Moment bounds for solutions to SDEs

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I've been looking at Kuo's book on stochastic integration, and I noticed that in Section 10.7, he proves some estimates for solutions to SDEs, written as $$dX_t = f(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dB_t$$.  One of these results, Theorem 10.7.2, is a bound on the fourth moment of the solution in terms of the data and the time of integration:
$$
E(|X_t|^4)\leq C(E|\xi|^4 + 1)e^{K(t-a)}
$$
for a solution on the finite interval $[a,b]$.  While I believe the result is correct, I'm a bit troubled by the derivation.  Kuo obtains it by, essentially applying the Itô isometry and Jensen's inequality to the term
$$
\left(\int_a^t \sigma(s, X_s)dB_s\right)^4.
$$
Or, at least, that's how I'm reading the proof.  What troubles me is that it would seem that you need to know
$$
\int_a^t E|\sigma(s,X_s)|^4 ds < \infty
$$
before the isometry can be applied.  I believe this can all be justified by  regularizing the problem the problem and passing to a limit, but I wanted to see if my reasoning is correct, or if there is some way to argue around this point.

Comment: Kou has used Bellman-Gronwall and Holder Inequality and lemma 10.7.1

Comment: Yes, but his Lemma 10.7.1 assumes a finite L^4 norm of, what I think is the sigma(s,X_s) term.

Comment: Yes but it has been said $\sigma(t,X_t)$ and $f(t,X_t)$ satisfy Lipschitz condition

Comment: Indeed $|\sigma(t,x)|^4\le C(1+x^2+x^4)$

Comment: Therefore $\int_{a}^{b}\mathbb{E}[\sigma^4(s,X_s)]ds<\infty$

Comment: How does that help? All it says is that $\int_a^b E|\sigma(s,X_s)|^4 ds \leq \int_a^b E|X_s|^4 ds$, but you still need to know that this is finite, which is what Theorem 10.7.2 is trying to prove.